# Which is the best open source Project management tool which supports defect management as well?

Tags: test-management, quality-center, defect-tracking

I am working for a start-up company as a Product Quality Assurance Engineer. I have to do requirement management, test case management, and defect management. And also to generate a report at the end of testing. 
My basic requirement is to implement an open source Test management tool which should help me to manage my requirements, test cases, test sets, defects all in one place, something in line of HP QC. 
I know its a lot to ask as we cannot implement HP QC because of license costing and all.
It would be a great help if anyone can suggest any thing.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have problems in using a external hosting system, you can use a combination of [JIRA](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) (bug tracking) and [Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence)  (team collaboration and requirements managment).

For locally hosted systems, I would recommend [Bugzilla](https://www.bugzilla.org/) or [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/).

Details of these tools and and a list of others can be found [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/bug-tracking-system/).